# Parse indented strings to hierarhy with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I have this ugly select list with indents ("-") to illustrate hierarchy. I would like, using jquery, to get data from source to result.

**Source**

```
<option value="12">Subcontractor</option>
<option value="108">-Surveyor</option>
<option value="62">--Excavation works</option>
<option value="554">--Concrete works</option>
<option value="44">-Demolition works</option>
<option value="103">--Site preparation works</option>
<option value="67">--Excavation works</option>
<option value="40">--Contamination works</option>
```

Example shows 4 levels, but levels count is unknown.

**RESULT**

```
var result = {
  "Subcontractor":12 {
    "Surveyor":108 {
      "Excavation works":62,
      "Concrete works":554
    },
    "Demolition works":44 {
      "Site preparation works":103,
      "Excavation works":67,
      "Contamination works":40
    }
  }
};
```

Notice how option value is added to deepest level only. UPDATE: updated result for eacier code and consistency, parents were missing value, it should be esier to parse to this result.

My jquery skills are average, but I think I could figure this out if someone could suggest direction.

Comment: what is connection between one dimensional list of options and multi dimension object?... need more details as to goal here.

Comment: Updated question with more clear emphasis on "-" character used for representing hierarchy.

Comment: still not clear at all what objective is ..parse options to object? if so not enough to figure parent-child relationship, a written explanation would help

Comment: @henrijs It's hard to understand you when your examples don't even match each other.

Comment: updated question with real example

Comment: different language, but same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881037/indented-list-to-multidimensional-array/8882181#8882181

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var struct = {}, path = [], indentation = '-';

$('option').each(function (i, el) {
  var
    $el = $(el),
    val = $el.val(),
    label = $el.text(),
    depth = 0,
    parent = struct,
    i;

  while (label.substr(0, indentation.length) === indentation) {
    depth += 1;
    label = label.substr(indentation.length);
  }

  path = path.slice(0, depth);
  path[depth] = label;

  for (i = 0; i < path.length; i += 1) {
    if (typeof parent[path[i]] !== 'object') {
      parent[path[i]] = {};
    }

    if (i < path.length - 1) {
      parent = parent[path[i]];
    }
    else {
      parent[path[i]] = val;
    }
  }
});

console.log(struct);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5zqZQ/4/

previous version: http://jsfiddle.net/5zqZQ/3/

Comment: Thanak you for your reply. Im testing both suggestions. Running code as is gives error in firebug console "parent is undefined "if (typeof parent[path[i]] === 'undefined') {""

Comment: Can you make a fiddle with your test-code? In the fiddle above there is no such error, so this could be scope problem.

Comment: yes, actually both examples has same issue, other example says "tempParent is undefined "if( ! tempParent.items){"" I will fiddle.

Comment: @henrijs I updated the code a little, you may want to try the new version.

Comment: You are fast, actually I found a problem with real life HTML and there is no error anymore. I will check out new code, it looks a lot shorter.

Comment: Here is your code with JSON.stringify() http://jsfiddle.net/henrijs/LSNZr/3/ If I would like to get format as in OP "Result", should I edit your code or write some "replacer" function for JSON.stringify()?

Comment: I agree. I wanted to further integrate with optionTree jquery plugin http://kotowicz.net/jquery-option-tree/demo/demo.html and there is already issue for this http://code.google.com/p/jquery-option-tree/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=7

Comment: @henrijs Please have a look at the updated code. It will set leaf-nodes to there appropriate values. Of course non-leaf-nodes will will have there children as values (but this is in accordance to the given spec)

Answer (score 2):

I got you a pretty good start at parsing options to object. Spent longer on it than I had expected and value shows on each level with children being an object named "items" in all cases. With a little extra mapping and refactoring you can get it in format you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/charlietfl/Z6pzv/